# Gulp change working directory for entire task

Tags: task, frontend, backend, gulp, working-directory

I'm working on a gulp file that contains tasks for both the frontend and the backend of my site.
The task below for example will concat my scripts into app.js:

```
gulp.task 'frontend:scripts', ->
    gulp.src frontendPath(scriptsFolder, scriptsPattern)
        .pipe sourcemaps.init()
        .pipe coffee()
        .pipe concat 'app.js'
        .pipe sourcemaps.write('.')
        .pipe gulp.dest frontendPath(tempFolder, scriptsFolder)
```

As you can see I've created a helper to provide the correct frontend path:

```
frontendPath = (dirs...) -> path.join.apply null, ['frontend'].concat(dirs)
```

But I have to be really careful that all the steps of my task (especially .src and .dest) are executed in the frontend folder.

I know that you can use the `{ cwd: 'frontend' }` option to change the working directory for .src and .dest. But is there a way to change the whole working directory for a task?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `process.chdir` to change the working directory. We can make the change anywhere in a gulpfile, or in your situation, change it within a task.

```
gulp.task('frontend', function(){
  process.chdir('...');
  gulp.src(...)
});

gulp.task('backend', function(){
  process.chdir('...');
  gulp.src(...)
});
```

Make sure using the latest version of gulp,
this feature seems to be [added recently](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/blob/f323e4d312491bce2d173d99e606ac4f7f280b91/index.js#L109-L110).

Answer (score 4):

With the way that gulp works, it doesn't make sense to "change directories" in the steps between `src` and `dest`.

`gulp.src` reads files from disk into memory.  The `.pipe`s thereafter just pipe the contents of those files (and metadata related to the files - see [Vinyl file objects](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl) for more info) to other javascript functions, each of which just operates on the in-memory versions of the file.  That means they don't know about a working directory, or care about one.  They just see incoming data about files come in through pipe, do stuff to that data, and send it out through the next `.pipe`.

So I think that if you're truly paranoid about being in the parent director, a `cwd` to src and dest is the best you can do.

All of that to say, you could look at [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs), which allows you to change directories for the current node process.  I think this might be considered an anti-pattern when piping things around, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please note that I don't want to change the working folder in the steps between `src` and `dest`. I want the whole task to run on a subfolder. Now I have to prefix all globs with my subfolder (or provide `cwd:` to both `src` and `dest`). I was hoping for a better way.

Comment: fair enough, then I think the shelljs module might be your friend.  Fwiw, I think prefixing the sub-directories is a pretty common practice, though.

Comment: What if you want to run several commands in several folders and these commands only work on the current working directory? For example running `serverless deploy`