# SystemJs Builder remove part of name

Tags: systemjs

I have a folder structure after a transpile from typescript like this:
-build
--app
----a
----b
----c

where a,b, and c are supposed to be separate modules and bundled independently. So far, I can get the bundles to work, but the System.register names all have 'build/app/XXX' in front. I want to get rid of the 'build/app' part. How do i do this?

I've tried using baseUrl as './' as well as './build/app' to no avail. The only thing that changes the name is actually altering the paths i pass into builder.bundle from 'build/app/a/*' to 'a/*'. However this doesn't work since I dont have a folder called 'a' on the outermost level. I have also tried the path property on the builder config as '*':'build/app/*' but this throws errors as it passes files from my base directory in.

Edit: I'm running the builder using gulp. My gulpfile is at the same level as the build folder.

Comment: If you don't have anything else in the outermost level, you can try to run builder in the build/app directory and pass `'a/*'` to `builder.bundle` (this would not require setting baseUrl for builder at all)

Comment: I do have other files/folders in the outermost level. This is where my gulpfile is, which is what runs the builder. I'll edit my post with that info.

Comment: You can try to create and run standalone builder script, then if it works you can change working dir in gulp for the build task using `process.chdir` as in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310665/gulp-change-working-directory-for-entire-task

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately builder did not pick up the directory change from `process.chdir`. I did get it to work with a similar approach by writing a standalone build script and keeping it in the correct directory and then executing the script with a child process. Thanks for the idea.