# Gulp directory changing

Tags: gulp

I was following the answer (the one chosen by op) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310665/gulp-change-working-directory-for-entire-task) to change directory in my `gulpfile.js`. To test whether the directory was changed, I added another task that prints the current directory. When run, both `tasks` are executed without any errors. However, `console.log` prints the address
 of the parent directory instead of the directory that was navigated into in the previous task.

Here's how I setup my directory, gulpfile.js and package.json.

`directory tree`

```
-- auth
---- gulpfile.js
---- package.json
---- other js scripts
---- <dest_folder>
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
/// TASKS
gulp.task('directory-changer', changeDirectory);
gulp.task('directory-printer', printCD);
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('directory-changer', 'directory-printer'));
/// TASKS
function changeDirectory(done) {
  process.chdir(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dest'));
  gulp.src()
  done();
}
function printCD(done) {
  console.log(__dirname);
  done();
}
```

`pacakge.json`

```
{ // other properties
    "scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"run-gulp": "node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js"
},
// other fields
```

The output generated:

```
npm run run-gulp

> auth@1.0.0 run-gulp <PROJECT_PATH>/
> node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js

[13:42:48] Using gulpfile <PROJECT_PATH>/gulpfile.js
[13:42:48] Starting 'default'...
[13:42:48] Starting 'directory-changer'...
[13:42:48] Finished 'directory-changer' after 1.14 ms
[13:42:48] Starting 'directory-printer'...
<PROJECT_PATH>/
[13:42:48] Finished 'directory-printer' after 387 μs
[13:42:48] Finished 'default' after 4.81 ms
```

Now my I think that it maybe because the `__dirname` is printing the execution path of the script rather than the changed directory. Is that the case or is there something else going on?

Comment: You're right, `__dirname` is always the path of the directory where the module is. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for confirming that. Is there any way to do what I'm trying?

Comment: You may use `process.cwd()` or, IMO better, `path.resolve("./")` (don't forget `const path = require("path")`)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Was just about to confirm that I tried the same and it worked. Thanks again.